# Summing values in loop VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to sum a series of values based on unique identifiers I have isolated using dictionary keys, via the code below:

```
SearchVar = dictionary.Keys()(v)

Set FoundVar = CurrentPage.Find(What:=SearchVar, LookIn:=xlValues, _ 
LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
Set nextVar = CurrentPage.FindNext(FoundVar)

If Not FoundVar Is Nothing Then

Do Until FoundVar = nextVar

    tempsum = tempsum + ws.Cells(FoundVar.Row, [ReferenceCell].Column).Value

     Set nextVar = CurrentPage.FindNext(nextVar)

    Loop

    End If
```

However when I do so, the tempsum stay at 0. I'm certain that the cell reference in the tempsum addition portion is referencing the correct (non-zero) cells. What could be causing this issue?

Editing to add comment from below: The loop will indeed run only once. I modified it to run multiple times if there are multiple values by changing it to

```
Do until FoundVar.Address = NextVar.Address
```

but in these cases it doesn't sum the value for the last instance of FoundVar (as the FoundVar and NextVar addresses are the same). Any suggestions on how to have it include the last value as well? I'm thinking it can be done by saying 'Do until FoundVar.Address is Nothing" or so, but not sure on the correct syntax.

Comment: And this could not be done with a SUMIF()?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to check the values? It looks as if your do loop will only run once.

Comment: SJR: Thank you! The loop will indeed run only once. I modified it to run multiple times if there are multiple values by changing it to 'Do until FoundVar.Address = NextVar.Address, but in these cases it doesn't sum the value for the last instance of FoundVar (as the FoundVar and NextVar addresses are the same). Any suggestions on how to have it include the last value as well?

Comment: The usual way is to store the address of the first found cell, and then your do loop runs while the next found address is not the same as the first address (or until the next address is the same as the first address). You should be able to find examples if you google 'find next loop' or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some mistake. Try this code.

```
Dim FoundVar As Range
Dim strAddress As String
SearchVar = dictionary.Keys()(v)

Set FoundVar = CurrentPage.Find(What:=SearchVar, LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

'Set nextVar = CurrentPage.FindNext(FoundVar)


    If Not FoundVar Is Nothing Then
        strAddress = FoundVar.Address
        Do
        tempsum = tempsum + ws.Cells(FoundVar.Row, [ReferenceCell].Column).Value

         Set FoundVar = CurrentPage.FindNext(FoundVar)

        Loop Until strAddress = FoundVar.Address


    End If
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing it with sumifs, but I tested that and it works!